# UICollectionView Cell with a thick border

Tags: swift

I am attempting to create a round collection view cell.

In the cell I have a red UIView that is 0 from top, leading, trailing, and bottom. Inside of that cell I have another view which is white and it is 4 from the top, leading, trailing, and bottom. Within that view is a UILabel and a UIImageView.

The goal would be to have 2 cells per column and it is has a red ring around a white circle and text and an image.

To create the round UIViews I have an extension for UIView like this

```
extension UIView {
  func createRoundView() {
    layer.cornerRadius = frame.size.width/2
    clipsToBounds = true
  }
}
```

Inside of my **cellForItemAt** I say

```
cell.whiteBackgroundView.createRoundView()
cell.colorStatusView.createRoundView()
```

The goal is on the left, but what is happening is on the right.

[image]

Here is my Storyboard

[image]

The constraints are all blue, nothing red.

And to get the 2 cell per column I use this delegate method

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let padding: CGFloat = 25
    let collectionCellSize = collectionView.frame.size.width - padding
    return CGSize(width: collectionCellSize/2, height: collectionCellSize/2)
}
```

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

In the end it doesn't matter if I have a view within a view. I change the ring or border color based on other data....so I just need to be able to easily change that border color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is not enough, to tell what's going on there... try to set all

```
backgroundColors to .clear
```

then set those properties to your view

```
customView.layer.cornerRadius = half of your width
customView.layer.borderWidth = 5
customView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
```

Answer (score 0):

Using @blinkmeoff answer I figured it out mostly (although follow up question to come)

Inside the cell class I added the following

```
self.backgroundViewContainer.layoutIfNeeded()       
self.backgroundViewContainer.layer.cornerRadius = min(backgroundViewContainer.frame.size.width, backgroundViewContainer.frame.size.height)/2
self.backgroundViewContainer.clipsToBounds = true
```

I kept getting weird shapes by just doing the /2 so I added the min(ba...

and that got me perfect circles